# How to raise an event when a Property changes in the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, events, caliburn.micro, propertychanged

I'll do my best to explain in detail what I'm trying to do.

I'm working with Caliburn.Micro Framework in a WPF project. I have a Model Class called DataModel which have two properties, Tag which is a string and DataValues which is a List of double values:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WPFUI.Models
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public List<double> DataValues { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I added a Combobox to the View where it's Items are all the Tags of some created objects of DataModel Class as a BindableCollection Property in the ViewModel:

```
private BindableCollection<DataModel> _data = new BindableCollection<DataModel>();

public BindableCollection<DataModel> Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set { _data= value; }
        }
```

And in UI:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Data" DisplayMemberPath="Tag" />
```

The BindableCollection is generated from each DataColumn of a DataTable (each column of the table is an object where the Header is the Tag Property of string type and row values are the DataValues Property of List type).

**What I'm looking for** is to create a Property called SelectedData in ViewModel that notifies changes of the Selection in the Combobox to the ViewModel and then access to the DataValues Property of the SelectedItem to pass that List to a Chart Values (I'm using [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/)) that sets a SeriesCollection Property that are linked to the UI.

Something like this:

```
private DataModel _selectedData;
public DataModel SelectedData
        {
            get { return _selectedData; }
            set
            {
                _selectedData= value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedData);
            }
        }

// Code to handle the DataObject selected in the Combobox 
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = DataObject.Tag,
                Values = DataObject.DataValues.AsChartValues() // LiveCharts
            },
        };
//

public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
```

**Note:** SeriesCollection must implement NotifyPropertyChanged in order to notify the UI the change of the Property.

**Summary**

In other words what I'm trying to do is notify the source that a Property change in the UI and then manipulate the DataObject (which is defined with the SelectedItem of the Combobox) inside the ViewModel to show new data in the UI (notifying changes in SeriesCollection Property).

How can I do to achieve this?

**EDIT**

If there is a PersonModel Class with FirstName and LastName properties instead of a DataModel Class, something like the following could be done in the View:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="People"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="SelectedPerson_LastName" />
```

And in the ViewModel:

```
public BindableCollection<PersonModel> People
        {
            get { return _people; }
            set { _people = value; }
        }

        public PersonModel SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return _selectedPerson; }
            set
            {
                _selectedPerson = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedPerson);
            }
        }
```

Then any time you change the selection of the Combobox the text of the TextBlock will update due to the line:

`<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="SelectedPerson_LastName" />`

where the LastName property is binded in `x:Name="SelectedPerson_LastName"`

I'm trying to implement a similar approach but I can't make `x:Name="SelectedData_DataValues"` directly in order to update the chart. Instead I need to set the SeriesCollection property setting the Values with the SelectedData.Datavalues property. But that's exactly what I don't know how to do.

Comment: Not sure where exactly the problem is. You can bind a ComboBox's SelectedItem or SelectedValue property to a property in your view model, and do any desired updates of the view model in the setter of that property. Such a Binding is TwoWay by default, so your view model gets updated whenever the user selects an item in the ComboBox.

Comment: @Clemens The problem is I don't know how to get and manipulate the DataObject (SelectedItem of Combobox) in the ViewModel. I need to convert the DataObject.DataValues List to Values inside SeriesCollection Property of the chart. Then I can do what you are saying and bind SeriesCollection property to the chart in the UI (I already have that) but I cannot bind the DataObject.DataValues List to the chart directly.

Comment: @Clemens The goal is when I change the SelectedItem in the Combobox (Tag changes) the chart should change due to the Values of it's SeriesCollection changes.

Comment: There is only `DisplayMemberPath="Tag"` in your question. How is Tag supposed to change then? You probably also want to set `SelectedValuePath="Tag"`  and bind SelectedValue.

Comment: @Clemens In Combobox I only display the Tag property of all DataModel objects. Am i missing something? 

I thought in: SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedData, Mode=OneWayToSource}", and then in the chart XAML <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">. 
But can't figure out how to use that to get what I want.

Comment: Apparently you aren't doing anything appropriate in the SelectedData setter. There is no built-in magic that would tell the UI that SeriesCollection has changed.

Comment: @Clemens That's what I'm asking. **What I'm looking for** is to create a Property called SelectedData in ViewModel that notifies changes of the Selection in the Combobox to the ViewModel and then access to the DataValues Property of the SelectedItem to pass that List to a Chart Values (I'm using LiveCharts) that sets a SeriesCollection Property that are linked to the UI.

Comment: @Queeng4: What property is changed in the UI?

Comment: @mm8 The property that changes will be SelectedData which it's what I want to create. Would be something like this:

private DataModel _selectedData;

public DataModel SelectedData
        {
            get { return _selectedData; }
            set
            {
                _selectedData= value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedData);
            }
        }

Comment: @mm8 When Combobox selection changes then SelectedData changes and due to each Item of the Combobox is a DataModel object I want to access to DataValues property of the selected Item inside ViewModel to set the SeriesCollection property which is binding to the UI and modify the chart.

Comment: Why can't you just bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to a `SelectedData` source property?

Comment: @mm8 You are saying SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedData, Mode=OneWayToSource}" in Combobox like I commented above? Yes, I think it's the first step but then how I should continue?

Comment: @mm8 I edit the question in order to clarify what I'm trying to do. Hope it helps to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally i got it:

```
private DataModel _selectedData;

public DataModel SelectedData
        {
            get { return _selectedData; }
            set
            {
                _selectedData = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedData);

                if (SelectedData != null)
                {
                    SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
                    {
                        new LineSeries
                        {
                            Title = SelectedData.Tag,
                            Values = SelectedData.DataValues.AsChartValues()
                        },
                    };
                }  
            }
        }
```

In XAML View:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" x:Name="Data"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedData, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Tag" />
```

And now SeriesCollection Property must implement NotifyPropertyChanged:

```
private SeriesCollection _seriesCollection;

public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection
        {
            get { return _seriesCollection; }
            set {
                    _seriesCollection = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SeriesCollection);
                }
        }
```

In XAML View:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
```

I couldn't have done it without the invaluable help. Thanks everyone!